# $A=I_n+uu^t$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, orthogonality

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix and let $u\neq 0 $ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$A=I_n+uu^t$$ ($t$ is the transpose). I was asked to show that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.

It easy just to check that $A=A^t$ and the identity hold. Now let us define $A^{-1}$ inverse of matrix $A$ as
$$A^{-1}=I_n+\alpha uu^t.$$ I want to find the real alpha for which $$A^{-1}=I_n+\alpha uu^t$$ hold.
My idea is to assume that $A$ can be decomposed as sum of orthogonal and identity matrix like $$A=I_n+uu^t.$$  Namely if $A$ is symmetric positive definite this means that $u$ is orthogonal implies
$ uu^t=I_n$ gives $A=2I_n $ and $A^{-1}= I_n+\alpha I_n $ then $AA^{-1}=I_n$ implies that $(2\alpha+2)I_n=I_n$ yield for $\alpha$ to be $-\frac{1}{2}$. Is what I have got true ?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Just use the property that $AA^{-1}=I_n$ and find $\alpha$ that makes this identify true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you think that $uu^t = I_n$. First of all, $u$ can be any vector (even the zero vector) and $I_n + uu^t$ is symmetric and positive definite. Secondly, $uu^t$ is a rank 1 matrix and $I_n$ is rank $n$ so they can never be equal (well not unless $n = 1$).

The correct identity is

$$(I_n + uv^t)^{-1} = I_n - \frac{1}{1 + v^tu} uv^t.$$

This is called the [Sherman-Morrison Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Comment: what is alpha ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik $-\frac{1}{1 + u^tu}$